# Solving matrix equation $A^TXA=X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix, $X$ a matrix with $n\times n$ inderterminants, is there a way to solve the matrix equation  $A^TXA=X$? If not, is there any numerical way to solve it, in particular for matrix over finite fields?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes I think the other post should answer my question

Comment: Nick, note that your matrix equation is a (discrete) [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the notes. Lynapunov equation is usually over the real numbers, I wonder if there is a version for solving such equation over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristics?

Comment: Yes, but the vectorization "trick" is the same regardless of field.